# error with vector::reverse_iterator in debug mode but not in release

Tags: c++, vector, stl, reverse-iterator

I use reverse_iterator to look up my vector and using pop_back to erase elements.But it causes some error in debug mode. My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student{
    string name;
    int score;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Student> testVec;
    testVec.push_back(Student{ "Lilei",50 });
    testVec.push_back(Student{ "YangFeifei",80 });
    testVec.push_back(Student{ "WuMing",80 });
    for (auto it = testVec.rbegin(); it != testVec.rend(); ++it){
        if (it == testVec.rbegin()) continue;
        while (it != testVec.rbegin()) {
            std::cout << &(*testVec.rbegin()) << ", ";
            std::cout << &(*it) << std::endl;

            testVec.pop_back();

            std::cout << &(*testVec.rbegin()) << ", ";
            std::cout << &(*it) << std::endl; // where error occur!
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: There is a good chance that if a debug build catches something there is something wrong. In release build then things seem to work but in a lot of cases you will be changing memory where you don't want to, and you will only find that out later. By then it isharder to debug... so take your debug build warning seriously!

Comment: Please include errors in the question when you receive them.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation for [`std::vector<>::pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) says that:

> Iterators and references to the last element, as well as the end() iterator, are invalidated.

Therefore, your `it` iterator is invalid after you called `pop_back()`. The behaviour of dereferencing this iterator is undefined, so your program's behaviour will be unpredictable.

For your particular case, it's possible that in debug builds there are some additional methods for the runtime to determine that you have made a mistake, but these checks may be costly for performance so may not be included in a release build. In any case, the behaviour is not guaranteed. The solution is to not use `it` after calling `pop_back()`.

Comment: I thought that my `it` iterator is not to the last element before calling `pop_back()`.And I tested some different cases.The case that `it` iterator points to the second element from the bottom before `pop_back()`  and the case that iterator points to the third element from the bottom.And the result shows that it occurs error in the first case but not in the second case.So both of the  iterator points to the last element befor and after calling `pop_back()` will be invalid.Right?